# Solving thus summation

Tags: summation, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

$F_1 = 1, F_2 = 2, F_i = F_{i - 1} + F_{i - 2} (i > 2)$.

A new number sequence $Ai(k)$ by the formula:

$A_i(k) = F_i × i^k (i ≥ 1)$.I need  to calculate the following sum: $A_1(k) + A_2(k) + \dots+ A_n(k)$. This answer has to be found modulo a large prime.

Please note $k$ will not exceed $20$.

I need to calculate the sum $A_1(k) + A_2(k) + \dots+ A_n(k)$ .

Comment: And what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Your sequence is the [Fibonacci numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number), with generating function:
$$
F(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} F_n z^n = \frac{z}{1 - z - z^2}
$$
Now, if you have the sequence $\langle a_n \rangle$ with $A(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n z^n$,
by differentiating you have:
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d} A}{\mathrm{d} z} &= \sum_{n \ge 0} n a_n z^{n - 1} \\
z \frac{\mathrm{d} A}{\mathrm{d} z} &= \sum_{n \ge 0} n a_n z^n
\end{align}
So you have to apply the "differentiate, multiply by $z$" $k$ times to $F(z)$ to get the generating function for the sequence $\langle n^k F_n \rangle$.

From the generating function $A(z)$ you get the generating function for the sequence $\langle \sum_{0 \le k \le n} a_k \rangle$ as $A(z) / (1 - z)$ (multiply $(1-z)^{-1} = 1 + z + z^2 + \cdots$ by $A(z)$ to see why). After all this work you'll need the coefficients. For smallish values of $k$ a computer algebra system should give the answers.